# Flutter and external JAR Library: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, olingo

Im trying to use olingo with Flutter on Android. I set up my channel and I can call the library but I keep getting this message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(28391): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28391): Process: com.example.odata, PID: 28391
E/AndroidRuntime(28391): org.apache.olingo.client.api.http.HttpClientException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/AndroidRuntime(28391):    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataRequest.doExecute(AbstractODataRequest.java:312)
```

So it looks like it is running on the main thread - which is a no go as this would block. I tried the looper to ask Java to run on the UI Thread:

```
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                        // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                        Log.i("test", "using " + call.method);
                        String serviceUrl = "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/";
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (call.method.equals("getMetaData")) {
                                    String metadata;
                                    final Edm edm = ODataClientFactory.getClient().getRetrieveRequestFactory().getMetadataRequest(serviceUrl).execute().getBody();
                                    metadata = edm.toString();

                                    if (metadata != "") {
                                        result.success(metadata);
                                    } else {
                                        result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Metadata cannot read.", null);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    result.notImplemented();
                                }


                            }
                        });
```

But Im still getting the same error.

So how exactly can I deal with external JAR Library which are doing blocking operations ? To my understanding an external call is a Future anyway so it will not block my Flutter thread anyway - but Android Java does not think so ...

This is my method call in flutter

```
Future<void> _getMetaData() async {
    String metadata;
    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getMetaData');
      metadata = result;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      metadata = e.message;
    }

    setState(() {
      _metadata = metadata;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, this is the solution for anyone that may be interested:

```
public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("getMetaData")) {
       class MetadataLoader extends AsyncTask<String , Integer, String> {
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                 // call your Java library method here, including blocking methods        
                 return your_return_value;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String _result) {
                  // your_return_value is now passed in _result
                  result.success(_result);
            }


       }

       new MetadataLoader().execute(); // Start the Async

}
```

On the flutter side,

```
    Future<void> _getMetaData() async {
        String metadata;
        try {

          final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getMetaData');

          // do something with the result

          // the Flutter thread will stop at the await and resume when the Java
          // will call result.success

        }
   }
```

Comment: didnt work, 
show err from IDE, 
method success must be called from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new Java thread or `Worker`. (Note that the "main" thread and the "UI" thread are the same thing - so by posting to the main looper you've ended up in the same place - trying to do network i/o on the main thread.)

Yes, the Flutter engine is running in different threads, but you still need to leave the main native thread unblocked as it is responsible for detecting user input, etc.

Also note that when your blocking activity completes - on its non-main thread - it will likely want to deliver the response to Dart. To do this it will need to use part of your code above - to post the results back to the main thread, which can then invoke method channel operations.

You'll probably want to use your method channel bi-directionally. From flutter to native to request an operation (returning, say, a sequence number), and from native to flutter to deliver the results (quoting the sequence number so that the result can be tied back to the request).